# Grouping Output Pattern in Regex- Python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to get only the sentences which match the regex pattern as output and avoid these NONE, how do i group the output which matches the pattern?

`import re
regex = re.compile('(.*)(?:India)')
with open("D:/txt_res/abc.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        result = regex.search(line)
        print(result)`

The output which im getting is

```
None
None
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 101), match='Email: abc.bitz@gmail.com'>
None
None
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 47), match='XYZ Engineer at ABC Organization, Bangalore'>
None
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 32), match='Intern at S360, Bangalore'>
None
None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just test for `None`:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('(.*)(?:India)')
with open("D:/txt_res/abc.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        match = regex.search(line)
        if match is not None:
            print(match)
```

Comment: Awesome and so simple :) Thanks @finwood

Comment: Done @finwood :) Just one more clarification, is it possible that i store each of the matched patterns in separate variables?

Comment: The match's `group()` function holds the matched pattern, so you could append it to a list: `lst = [] ... lst.append(match.group())`